# Oracle : Rows to columns based on column value where value is not fixed

Tags: sql, oracle, transpose

I have the below sample data in the Oracle table where the records for VALUE can be increased or decreased for LOCATION and LINE. For LINE **BLOCK** and LOACTION **OP-40-BLOCK** the VALUE can appear n number of times.:

> [image: Blockquote]
>
>  I want the below output data :
> [image]
>
> I have tried the below query :

```
SELECT OP,VAL3,VAL1,VAL2,(VAL1+VAL2+VAL3) TOTAL FROM(
SELECT LOCATION OP, REGEXP_SUBSTR(VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, 1) AS VAL1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, 2) AS VAL2,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, 3) AS VAL3
FROM
(SELECT LOCATION,LISTAGG(VALUE,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LOCATION) VALUE
FROM t_rk WHERE LINE='BLOCK'
GROUP BY LOCATION));
```

but I am not getting the desired result. Please help.

Comment: How do you tell which is the first, second and third value for a location? Or doesn't it matter? Can we also return `'OP-10 BLOCK 1 2 44` instead of `'OP-10 BLOCK 44 2 1`?

Comment: The values sequence does not matter. It can be based on the appearance starting either from first to last or last to first. It can be **OP-10 BLOCK 1 2 44**

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your data as formatted text into your request instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, number your rows per location, so to define which the first, second and third value is. Then aggregate by location.

```
select
  location,
  max(case when rn = 1 then value end) as value_1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then value end) as value_2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then value end) as value_3,
  sum(value) as total
from
(
  select
    location,
    value,
    row_number() over (partition by location order by value) as rn
  from t_rk 
  where line = 'BLOCK'
) numbered
where rn <= 3
group by location
order by location;
```

Comment: in my data rn is not fixed. It can be n number of times.

Comment: Then you cannot do this in a SQL query. A query result is a table, and a table has a fixed number of defined columns. Your task is a GUI layout thing and is something that you should do in your app instead. (Just loop through the rows with a programming langauge and fill a grid accordingly). Another option is dynamic SQL, but that includes a programming language, too. Wite a query to determine the number n. Then generate a query for n rows and run this.

Comment: They are various solutions on the net you can google for, to do dynamic pivoting in ORACLE using pipelined functions and polymorphic table functions but as previous comment told you you will need to prepare your data with unique id. (look for "Anton's pivoting" on amis.nl site and for PTF on ORACLE's livesql site).
To have both dynamic pivot AND the sum of the pivoted columns you will have to go for custom PTF.